# Override EJB 3 Stateless session bean's methods by "pure" class

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

We have an application with an EJB 3.0 module. We want to override the business logic in the EJB implementation. Is it possible?

Once I override, how can lookup or inject the overridden session bean?

```
public interface TestRemote {
    public String result(String arg1, String arg2);
}

@Stateless
public class TestBeanOne implements TestRemote {
    public String result(String arg1, String arg2) {
        return "TestBeanOne " + arg1 + arg2;
}

//Is the below code possible?
public class TestBeanTwo extends TestBeanOne {
    public String result(String arg1, String arg2) {
        return "TestBeanTwo " + arg1 + arg2;
}
```

Comment: It will take minimal effort & time to check whether it's possible or not, always try first & then come up with issues encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that code is possible you just need to annotate it. Annotations can be overridden by deployment descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that an EJB is still a simple Java class at heart. Everything that's possible with a Java class is possible with an EJB.
So Just lookup the classes as you would, any Session Bean.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `TestBeanTwo` class doesn't have `@Stateless` on purpose, the class will not be a stateless session bean and therefore will not be able to be looked up or injected as an EJB. Even with `@Stateless` or a declaration in an `ejb-jar.xml` file, the `TestBeanTwo` bean class would not expose the `TestRemote` interface, but merely a no-interface view that happens to have `public String result(String, String)` available.

The EJB 3.1 specification says in the section `4.9.2.1 Session Bean Superclasses` (page 121):

*A session bean class is permitted to have superclasses that are themselves session bean classes. However, there are no special rules that apply to the processing of annotations or the deployment descriptor for this case. For the purposes of processing a particular session bean class, all superclass processing is identical regardless of whether the superclasses are themselves session bean classes. In this regard, the use of session bean classes as superclasses merely represents a convenient use of implementation inheritance, but does not have component inheritance semantics.*

And on the same page in the specification:

*The client views exposed by a particular session bean are not inherited by a subclass that also happens to define a session bean.*

I think these two excerpts from the specification explain the question well enough.